# flask send image as bytes with extra information

Tags: flask, byte

I am trying to return an image (as bytes) plus extra information (e.g description) using flask. Returning the image alone works well using *send_file*. When I tried both of them the only way I got it to work is using

> jsonify({'img':json.dumps(list(imgByteArr.getvalue())),'desc':"....."}).

When I get the response from the client using curl_response.json()['img'] it is '[ 3, 189, ...., 154, 0, 255, 217]'. How can I get it back to the original bytes.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
"".join([str(x) for x in json.loads('[23, 423, 435, 5]')])
```

but it is not an optimal way to get this work.
Sending image bytes in JSON object is not a proper way to send data: you should better send links or ids to access images.